# CSS for Dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a code like this in MVC 3
@Html.DropDownList("SomeID", "Select ID")
i need to apply some styles to this Dropdown.

this doesn't working for me " new { @class="dropdown" }".

Help me, thanks in advance.

Thanks,
[Ramesh Kumar](http://iprameshkumar.com/)

Answer (score 0):

when you use like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("SomeID", "Select ID")
```

then this is not working `" new { @class="dropdown" }"`

so for use your css then you use like this

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "ID", "Name"), "select", new { @ID = "ddlCountry", @class = "text", Style = "width: 150px;", onchange = "javascript:cascadingdropdown();" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Citys.countryID)
</div>
```

i think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("MyDropdown", MySelectList, new { @class="mycssclass" })
```